# Adding a 2D Array to a 3D Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Im struggling a little with stacking two matrices on top of each other. I'm using the pyKalman package, which when updated, returns a tuple of matrices. One with an updated estimate (`new_pred` a 1 x 2 vector) and the corresponding covariance matrix (`new_cov` a 2 x 2 matrix).

After the update, I want to stack the returned values to their corresponding outputs, for a recursive smoothing of the data, through these estimates.

The following is how it is currently implemented.

```
for meas in onlineObservations:
    (new_pred, new_cov) = kf.filter_update(states_pred[-1], cov_pred[-1], meas)
    states_pred = np.vstack((states_pred, new_pred))
    cov_pred = np.stack((cov_pred, new_cov), axis=0)
```

Which works really well for the updated estimate (the 1x2 vector), but fails when i try to add `new_cov` to the array called `cov_pred`. For good measure:

```
states_pred.shape = (900,2)
cov_pred.shape = (900, 2, 2)
```

I've tried changing the axis of "stack" to no avail. It's probably something elementary, but i've been struggling with it for the past hour, and cannot seem to find a "simple" solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work -

```
cov_pred = []
for meas in onlineObservations:
    (new_pred, new_cov) = kf.filter_update(states_pred[-1], cov_pred[-1], meas)
    states_pred = np.vstack((states_pred, new_pred))
    cov_pred.append[new_cov]
cov_pred = np.stack(cov_pred, axis=0)
```

But since you want to update array which you are using already in code, you should use `np.concatenate`

```
for meas in onlineObservations:
    (new_pred, new_cov) = kf.filter_update(states_pred[-1], cov_pred[-1], meas)
    states_pred = np.vstack((states_pred, new_pred))
    cov_pred = np.concatenate((cov_pred, np.reshape(new_cov, (1,2,2))), axis=0)
```

Comment: But i call the last element of cov_pred, which does not allow me to perform the last line?

Comment: Till the time you have all the arrays of same dimension, np.stack will work, thats why I have saved everything in a list first and then stacking.

Comment: it returns "all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions".

Comment: fixed the number of dim

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make it work by converting `cov_pred` to a list, and then use:

```
cov_pred.append(new_cov)
```

And then re-convert it back again after the for loop. But it seems tedious - at least if there's an even better way!

Comment: use np.concatenate

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your code inside a For Loop (While Loop will also do) and use 'Auto-index Enabled' and thats it....
At the output of Loop, LabVIEW will create a 3D data exactly as your requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure why LabVIEW is involved here... Can you elaborate your answer more?